# Imperativ mit Ihr/euch

Tags: imperative

In the children’s song *die Wanze* I found “Seht euch mal die Wanze an” and it left me confused. According to what I learned, the imperative has three forms: *du, ihr und Sie*. What about “Seht euch … an” or “Ruht euch aus”?

> Auf der Mauer, auf der Lauer, liegt ’ne kleine Wanze
>   Seht euch mal die Wanze an
>   Wie die Wanze tanzen kann
>   Auf der Mauer, auf der Lauer, liegt ’ne kleine Wanze

Comment: Can you give a source for the infinitive being limited?

Comment: It is *ihr*....

Comment: What is your question? This is clearly the *ihr* imperative …

Comment: how about plural imperative, yes?

Comment: @klh I feel the strong urge to say ‘how about no?’ ^^'

Answer (score 1):

The verb is *sich (dat.) etwas (acc.) ansehen*: to watch something. So *euch* here is dative, and *die Wanze* is accusative. In the singular, it would be

> Sieh dir mal die Wanze an